# python : convert string to time object

Tags: python, django

I got a string `date`

```
date = '2014-12-18T19:00:00-07:00'
```

But I have no idea how to save this to `models.DateTimeField( null=True,blank=True)`

Please help me how to convert this sting to datetime object 
Thank you very much

Comment: do you care about the timezone?

Comment: yes,I want to change to UTC

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Traditionally, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strptime

```
# %z is supported in Python 3.2 onwards. Older versions of python don't support that.
from datetime import datetime
date = '2014-12-18T19:00:00-07:00'
format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(date, format)
print datetime_obj.strftime(format)
```

Alternatively, because you have an iso8601 sting format already, someone already wrote a parser for that. See http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/1.5

```
import dateutil.parser
date = '2014-12-18T19:00:00-07:00'
datetime_obj = dateutil.parser.parse(date)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's very clearly.I have a question,is  ````datetime_obj```` a UTC time???

Comment: It is, but you can convert it to a timestamp in your TZ via 'datetime.astimezone(tz)'
You can set it via the constructor too, but in this particular case, you're not instantiating a DT Object from the constructor call. You're parsing an iso8601 string to DT object.

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
format = "%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p" # the format your input date is in
date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, format)
```